# MySQL select into outfile, select data amount (file size limit)

Tags: mysql, sql, into-outfile

I am selecting huge amounts of data (~ 10-100 mbytes) from 400M-1G tables, I am using query:

`select log from logs_010110 where [cond] into outfile '/tmp/log.txt'`

the problem is - `/tmp/log.txt` file size EVERY time is `14134375 bytes == 15Mb` so I think there is some limit for select statement which I need to override to select big amounts of data. What variable controls this limit/how can I set it bigger?

Comment: Is there enough diskspace on the /tmp mount? Can your script finish, or is it limited in time (for example when called in php)? Try the mysql console, try different directories, try different tables. Still the same result?

Comment: Yep, there is enought space, my script have zero time limit, I've tries to use another dirs, but result same. There is something in mysql I suppose, because every time file size is fixed to concrete values, which is exactly 15 megabytes

Comment: How many lines does `wc -l /tmp/log.txt` give you? Is there a difference with `SELECT COUNT(*) where [cond]` ?

Comment: I don't have `LIMIT` statement in my select query at all

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase buffer_pool_size mysql param!